# Keyboard accessibility for Angular dialog box, not initial focus on dialog box

Tags: angular, accessibility

After user login, we are showing dialog box and on press of tab key, initial focus on the screen behind dialog box and at last it comes to dialog box. I am trying to do initial focus on dialog box after login screen

I tried this for dialog box

```
<div role="dialog" id="dialog1" aria-labelledby="dialog1_label" tabindex="0" aria-modal="true">
```

Its still not focusing on dialog box at first place , also I have tried giving `tabindex="-1"` to header, body and footer after login screen but it still initial focus on header, body and footer on press of tab key. Adding `tabindex="-1"` is not making any difference.

We are not using angular materials.

Comment: Are you using any other UI library? If not, you will need to do everything manually: focus the dialog: like `dialog1.focus()`, and trap focus inside the dialog by either intercepting _Tab_ keys or by setting `tabindex="-1"` on all focusable elements outside the dialog. It also should close on _Esc_.  See also [the `<dialog>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) and [the accessible Dialog pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/dialogmodal/)

Comment: I am thinking to do dialog1.focus() way, but don't know how should I approach, we have different component  for dialog and using that component all over the app. Also, any UI library will you recommend for this? I didn't find any reliable one  @Andy